# Dropdown Navbar in Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the navbar is resized, the dropdown doesn't seem to work. 
Is there anything wrong with my codes?
Is there any solution for this?

This is my HTML code.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">company</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="order.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i><span>&nbsp;Order</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;Cart</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i><span>&nbsp;Contact Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><span>&nbsp;About Us</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i><span>&nbsp;Register</span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>&nbsp;Login</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/5TATB/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you forgot to add jQuery library in fiddle.

Comment: @amol I added the jquery code at the js section. but it still didn't work.. this is the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/5TATB/1/

Comment: @user1023: you need to select or include jQuery library from left side dropdown. Check this Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/5TATB/4/
Click on bottom edge of the toggle button cause 'Result' text of jsfiddle is overlap there.

Comment: @amol
I tried to edit my code, and it did work. But when I tried to implement it on my code, it didn't seem to work. :( I included it at the last part of my body, with this, and the dropdown didn't work.

<script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

According to what I had saw in the console, you did not include jquery framework on `jsfiddle` and I am sure you did it exactly in your code.

[image: See this]

Bootstrap was built with a `jquery` complement. Before you can use the bootstrap nice javascript plugins you must include `jquery` before `bootstrap.min.js`.

[See documentation here!](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/5TATB/3/)

Comment: I tried to edit my code, and it did work. But when I tried to implement it on my code, it didn't seem to work. :( I included it at the last part of my body, with this, and the dropdown didn't work.

<script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: you sure the directory is correct and the said jquery file is there?

Comment: what was the error on the console when you click the button? Use the element inspector and paste the error..